# Navigation, Clear back stack when app stops

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using jetpack compose inside fragments flow,  here the nav host

```
compose_view.apply {
    setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
    setContent {
        EggNavigation()
    }
}

    fun EggNavigation() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
    
             NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = EggScreenExotic.MainScreen.route
        ) {}
}
```

the navigation is something like this
activity > fragment > compose egg list > egg details > open anther app >go to egg app > press back > activity is showing but activity >

but ...fragment > compose egg list > egg details > pressing back > egg list

why compose navigation is stop working

Comment: the second case , but what should I do with setViewCompositionStrategy

Comment: @PylypDukhov ..

Comment: Ok, looks like `setViewCompositionStrategy` is not related.  start by checking if `onCreate` has being called for the second time. Also please clarify your problem - "compose navigation stopd working" means that you can't navigate, or just reset to initial route? Are you pressing back button in an other app and yours appearing?

Comment: activity > fragment > compose egg list > egg details > open anther app >go to egg app > press back > activity is showing

but
activity > fragment > compose egg list > egg details > pressing back > egg list

Comment: which compose/navigation versions are you using? please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)